# Poisson regressions in ratio: why is the counterpart not significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, ratio

I am not a statistician and have limited knowledge about the underlying mathematics behind models but I am curious about something I found. I have count data, something like this: out of 150 words in a text, 50 are nouns, 100 are verbs. In another later text I have 200 words: 170 are nouns, 30 are verbs, etc. (this is a more simplified example for the sake of explanation).  The texts are differentiated by writing period. So I ran a (Quasi)Poisson regression for verbs over time including the number of total words as offset. The effect of time was negative and significant. When I ran the same model for nouns, I had a positive effect but no significance. How can I explain this? Why is one significant and the other (which is exactly the opposite) is not? Shall I suspect something weird in my data or am I missing some important thing about the definition of significance?

Comment: I am not sure I understand why this is odd or how nouns and verbs are opposites. There are several parts of speech: nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, pronouns, prepositions, conjunctions, interjections, numerals, articles, and determiners. It's conceivable that there could be fewer verbs and an insignificant change in nouns. Compare "wishin' and hopin' and thinkin' and prayin', plannin' and dreamin' each night of his charms" to "wishin' and hopin' and thinkin' and prayin', dreamin' all night long of his charms."

Comment: I know, I am simply interested in the distribution of these two in my research (I am a linguist) .

Answer (score 1):

While you wait for a proper answer, here's my informal explanation. If you split the data and run two independent analyses, each model doesn't "know" that verbs and nouns are complements.

In your case, for verbs you have 100 vs 30. In fact 100 vs 15 because the second set is twice as large. So the ratio is 100/15 = 6.7, quite a lot.

For nouns you have 50 vs 170, which gives 50/(170/2) = 0.59 (or 1.7 times as much, 1/0.59), which is not so striking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But by including the offset in a single model, am I not saying that there is a complement?

Comment: An offset is a covariate whose coefficient you don't need to estimate because you know already its effect (*e.g.* a text twice as long is expected to give twice as many verbs, other things being equal). The offset doesn't mean "so many out of that many" although in your case you can interpret it that way, but the model doesn't know that. Perhaps what you need is (quasi)binomial model or multinomial model?

Comment: Binomial as in a logistic regression? Thanks for your help.

Comment: *Binomial as in a logistic regression*: Yes, and consider also negative binomial

Comment: okay, so it is safe to run logistic regression on count data? I guess I would need to transform the dataset anyway